# Ansible command showing error Traceback

Tags: ansible

When running an ansible command, it shows the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ansible", line 4, in 
      import('pkg_resources').run_script('ansible==2.0.0', 'ansible')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2805, in 
      working_set.require(requires)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 696, in require
      needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
      raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute
```

What is the problem here, am I missing something.

Comment: How did you install Ansible? What command are you running?

Comment: Yes i installed from github, I follow instructions mentioned in this link [link](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#installing-the-control-machine)

Answer (score 0):

I think @tristan is on the right track. Ansible 2.0 is not yet released. With `ansible==2.0.0` in the output I would guess you installed Ansible from the git devel branch. Did you clone the repository recursive? Ansible depends on git submodules.

To install from git:

```
git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
cd ./ansible
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I git cloned the 2.0.0 ver w/o realizing it. I was working on the "writing modules" tutorial and needed the test module source. I'm going to git rm (or just regular rm) the whole source tree I have installed in ~/src/ansible. Then I'll have to re-clone it without the -recursive flag.

I'm not sure if installing the ansible source tree to ~/src/ansible is the best idea, as similar source stuff like ec2, foreman and heroku are in /usr/local. But I decided to roll the dice since putting ansible in /usr/local was throwing perm errors.

Comment: I was able to get past this problem: <br> 
`src:% rm -Rfv ansible`  src:%git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git -b v1.9.2-1 -- recursive  

#Chking Ansible Version  
src:% ansible --version  
ansible 1.9.2 configured  
module search path = None  
  
#Now my ansible timetest.py module tutorial doesn't throw an error:  
% ~/src/ansible/hacking/test-module -m ~/timetest.py